# Yii2: GridView Speed Optimization

Tags: gridview, yii2, kartik-v, yii2-grid

I'm using Yii2 GridView to display data from `ActiveDataProvider`, the speed of it is working nicely when its pagination-enabled. But when displaying all the rows, everything lags.

I'm using a normal Controller->View flow.

[image: Added Database Caching also]
[image: Normal Controller]

Comment: how many row you have in your result query ?

Comment: It depends, some tables go up as big as 90,000 records, or 20,000 records, or even it's really slow at 1,300 records

Comment: then keep in mind that without pagination all the rows are fetched and rendered .. so the question is why you want show from 1300 to 90000 records ????????

Answer (score 1):

Without pagination al the rows  are fetched by the ActiveDataProvider  and rendered dy gridview  ..

Regardless of performance. This is unhelpful in terms of an acceptable user experience.

If your  need is to have client  side of the totality of data, it is advisable to avoid the use of the ActiveDataProvider and the gridview, and alternatively use a sql command creat  with with `createCommand(....);` and sql and restrain the result as a JSON structure to process client / side

Comment: My issue is that sometimes if the user wants to load all the rows (for some reason), I have some Jquery UI that lags for example resizing the gridview itself.

Comment: the answer is clear  .. without pagination all the rows are fecthed  and renderd .. if you want more speed .. you can do as suggested ..  there are not other ways ..